# Rails Rspec Testing Controller New Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to test the new action in my controller. At the moment it looks like this:

Controller

```
def new
  @business = Business.new
  @business.addresses.build
end
```

Spec

```
describe 'GET #new' do
  it 'assigns a new business to @business' do
    get :new
    expect(assigns(:business)).to be_a_new(Business)

  end
end
```

I would like to test the line '@business.addresses.build'. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to create a mock object..

Comment: Try to check presence of `@business.addresses` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084346/testing-a-build-association-using-rspec-in-rails-3

Comment: In what situation, this piece of code will fail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about

```
expect(assigns(:business).addresses.first).to be_a_new(Address)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming build is a method, you only need test to ensure that build is called. You could do so by replacing the new `Business` with a mock that has an `addresses` attribute that expects to receive `:build`.

I haven't tested this, but I suspect you could do something like:

```
business = double('business')
addresses = double('addresses')
business.should_receive(:addresses).and_return(addresses)
addresses.should_receive(:build)
Business.stub(:new).and_return(business)
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this, because it's testing implementation rather than result. What if you changed `build` to be `new`? The result is the same, but your test would break.

Comment: That's true! It's a very brittle test, but he did ask how to test that specific line. Perhaps the bigger question is why that line is even in the controller. Should it be moved to the constructor?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to rails. I understand what a constructor is however not sure where it should be implemented using the mvc pattern. Would it be put in the model and called from the controller?

Comment: Inside your definition for Business, you can define a function called `initialize` that acts as the endpoint for `Business.new(...)`. In your case, it might contain `addresses.build` if you know that all business instances should build addresses.